# Integer polynomial, maximum number of consecutive integer values that it can reach.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Lets say I have an integer polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $n$ and $x_0,\dots,x_r \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$P(x_0) = 0$

$P(x_1) = 1$

$P(x_2) = 2$

$\dots$

$P(x_r) = r$

What is the largest $r$ that I can have (everything is integers)?

I have no idea how to approach this. I tried polynomial interpolation (which is usually a bad idea...), but that's a mess and I couldn't figure out how to force it to have integer coefficients. It would be nice to be able to turn this into a question of reducibility, so that I can use Gauss's lemma, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I don't have much intuition about this. Like, I know that with integer polynomials, you can only make them so wide without dividing, so maybe $r$ us not dependent on $n$, but then you can probably make it go up and down in such a way to hit arbitrary integer values, so that it would depend on $n$.

Hints?

Comment: To get lots of consecutives, we can use $P(x)=x((x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-r)+1)$. But for given degree, one may be able to do better.

Comment: Hmm, I will clarify my post, but $x_i$, and the coefficients of $P(x)$ are all integers.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, Is that polynomial unique?

Comment: I have not thought about the problem, just enough to write down an example. I used $x_i=i$. We can make the $x_i$ arbitrary distinct. That may give enough freedom to squeeze some extra consecutives.  The polynomial has degree $r+1$, so there is only $1$  degree of freedom left, even if we consider polynomials over the reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the fact that $(a-b)|(P(a)-P(b))$ for a polynomial $P$ with integer coefficients to obtain restrictions on $x_i$. You should be able to proceed from there.

Comment: Oh, wow, that pretty much answers it. $x_i = x_{i+1} \pm 1$, so $x_i$ are consecutive integers either increasing or decreasing. Take $P(x) - x - x_0$, it has $r+1$ roots which is the same as its degree, so it can't have any more roots. Andre's comment shows that you can have exactly $\mathrm{deg} P$ points.